# Count certain element in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

So I'm not familiar with javascript and kind of confused how to do logic with it. I have a json file that looks like this :

but i don't know how to do it for json in javascript. And also I think I maybe can use jquery for the "getJSON". Thank you.

Comment: Where is the json file? On your filesystem, a remote server or?

Comment: it's on my filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce to indroduce a counter/accumulator and loop through the genres array within the reduce to see if *Comedy* exists

```js
const input = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
      "Comedy ",
      " Drama ",
      " Sports"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
      "Adventure ",
      " Comedy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
      "Adventure ",
      " Fantasy ",
      " Sci-Fi ",
      " Drama"
    ]
  }
];

const result = input.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const isComedy = x.genres.some(y => y.trim() === 'Comedy')
  if (isComedy) acc += 1
  return acc;
}, 0)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to try it

Comment: should work, if you want to ignore the capital letters and still perform the count then add ```y.trim().toLowerCase()```

Answer (score 0):

```
let count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++) //use the length property to iterate through json.
{
if(jsonfile[i].genres.some(element=>element=="Comedy")) { //if the objects genres property have 1 or more element which is equal to "Comedy" then returns true
count++
}
}
```

Demo:

```js
let jsonfile = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Fantasy ",
        " Sci-Fi ",
        " Drama"
    ]
}];



let count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++)
{
if(jsonfile[i].genres.some(element=>element.trim()=="Comedy")) { //Trim fnuction get rids of spaces from start and end of the string
count++
}
}

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

One short way is:

```
const result = data.filter(e => e.genres.some(g => g.match(/comedy/i)));

console.log(result.length);
```

```js
const data = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
      "  Dark Comedy ",
      " Drama ",
      " Sports"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
      "Adventure ",
      " Comedy"
    ]
  },
  {
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
      "Adventure ",
      " Fantasy ",
      " Sci-Fi ",
      " Drama"
    ]
  }
]

const result = data.filter(e => e.genres.some(g => g.match(/comedy/i)));

console.log(result.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Try edit message
const data = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy",
        "Drama",
        "Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        "Comedy"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        "Fantasy ",
        "Sci-Fi ",
        "Drama"
    ]
}]

const countByGenre = (key) => {
  let genres = [];
  let counter = 0;
  data.map((item) => {
    genres.push(item);
  })

  genres.map((item) => {
    item.genres.map((item) => {
      if (item.toLowerCase() === key.toLowerCase()) return counter += 1;
    })
  })

  return counter;
}

console.log(countByGenre('comedy')) // will return 2
```

Demo https://playcode.io/590976

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way, main problem is that your json `genres` key contain value with space.

```js
let jsonfile = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Fantasy ",
        " Sci-Fi ",
        " Drama"
    ]
}]
let count = 0
for (i = 0; i < jsonfile.length; i++) {
    let genres = jsonfile[i]['genres']
    for (j = 0; j < genres.length; j++) {
        let value = genres[j].trim()
        if (value.toLowerCase() == 'comedy') 
            count = count + 1
    }
}
console.log(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to try it

Answer (score 0):

Can do this by a simple loop in Javascript.

```
var a = [{
    "cover_title": "Haikyuu!! TO THE TOP",
    "cover_studio": "Production I.G",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx106625-UR22wB2NuNVi.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "84%",
    "description": "The fourth season of Haikyuu!!\n\nThe Karasuno High School Volleyball Club finally won their way into the nationals after an intense battle for the Miyagi Prefecture Spring Tournament qualifiers. As they were preparing for the nationals, Kageyama is invited to go to All-Japan Youth Training Camp. At the same time, Tsukishima is invited to go to a special rookie select training camp for first-years in Miyagi Prefecture. Hinata feels panic that he\u2019s being left behind as one of the first-years and then decides to show up at the Miyagi Prefecture rookie select training camp anyway...\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Comedy ",
        " Drama ",
        " Sports"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Eizouken ni wa Te wo Dasu na!",
    "cover_studio": "Science SARU",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx109298-YvjfI88hX76T.png",
    "format": "TV",
    "duration": "79%",
    "description": "First year high schooler Midori Asakusa loves anime so much, she insists that \"concept is everything\" in animation. Though she draws a variety of ideas in her sketchbook, she hasn't taken the first step to creating anime, insisting that she can't do it alone. The producer-type Sayaka Kanamori is the first to notice Asakusa's genius. Then, when it becomes clear that their classmate, charismatic fashion model Tsubame Mizusaki, really wants to be an animator, they create an animation club to realize the \"ultimate world\" that exists in their minds.\n\n(Source: Crunchyroll)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Comedy"
    ]
},
{
    "cover_title": "Made in Abyss: Fukaki Tamashii no Reimei",
    "cover_studio": "Kinema Citrus",
    "cover_img": "https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/cover/large/bx100643-fPH9OgEKKvcI.jpg",
    "format": "Movie",
    "duration": "78%",
    "description": "Dawn of the Deep Soul continues the epic adventure of plucky Riko and Reg who are joined by their new friend Nanachi. Together they descend into the Abyss\u2019 treacherous fifth layer, the Sea of Corpses, and encounter the mysterious Bondrewd, a legendary White Whistle whose shadow looms over Nanachi\u2019s troubled past. Bondrewd is ingratiatingly hospitable, but the brave adventurers know things are not always as they seem in the enigmatic Abyss...\n\n(Source: Sentai Filmworks)",
    "genres": [
        "Adventure ",
        " Fantasy ",
        " Sci-Fi ",
        " Drama"
      ]}]

var comedy = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var obj = a[i];
    if(obj.genres.includes("Comedy ") || obj.genres.includes(" Comedy") || obj.genres.includes("Comedy")){
      comedy++
    }
}

console.log(comedy)
```